# Show only product with special prices

Tags: pagination, opencart, categories, price, opencart-3

Is it possible to show only products with special prices?

I put   {% if product.special %}  in my product_card.twig, and that works fine but then my pagination doesn't work correctly. It still shows the total number of products that belongs to that category.

I have 5 products in some category but pagination says "Showing 1 to 9 of 9 (1 pages)".

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You should edit your corresponding controller and model files by adding filter for that to count new quantity on your new condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new model function that get query from DB some thing like

```
public function getSpecialByCategory() {
   // your query here
}
```

and get result by controller then controller send it to your Twig file.